# Vectors of different objects and working with their iterators

Tags: c++, vector, indexing, iterator

I have two vectors of different objects and I'd like to work with their indexes and iterators.

Here is the code:

```
bool Database::Birth ( const string & name, const string & addr,
               const string & acc )
{
    SPerson personToAdd = SPerson ( name, addr );
    SAccount accountToAdd = SAccount ( acc );

    SPiter = lower_bound ( SPeople.begin ( ), SPeople.end ( ), personToAdd );

    /* this is the part I can't quite figure out */

    size_t iterDistance = distance ( SPeople.begin ( ), SPiter );
    SAiter = SAccounts.begin ( ) + iterDistance;

    // this is where the segfault is happening 
    if ( ( SPiter -> s_name == name &&
       SPiter -> s_addr == addr ) ||
       SAiter -> s_account == acc ) return false;

    SPeople.insert ( SPiter, personToAdd );
    SAccounts.insert ( SAiter, accountToAdd );

    return true;
}
```

It should be obvious what I am trying to do - I want to insert one object (SPerson) into a specific place in its vector (SPeople) and another object (SAccount) into its vector (SAccounts) under the same index. Is it possible to extract the "index" information from an iterator somehow?

I found several simmilar questions, but the solutions were very often working with loops, what I don't need (and actually can't use because of the performance). I definitely cannot change the part with the lower_bound function.

Comment: You are doing it right - calling `std::distance` from `SPeople.begin ()` gives you the index. Is there a problem that you see when you follow this approach?

Comment: You need an identifier here `Saiter HERE = SAccounts.begin ( ) + iterDistance;`. Other than that, this should work.

Comment: When `std::distance` is used with `RandomAccessIterator` arguments, it computes the distance in constant time. This is the case with `std::vector` iterators. However, you could just use the ordinary `-` subtraction operator instead of `std::distance`...

Comment: Whoa, I am surprised that I did this correctly. The problem is that I am seeing good old 'Segmentation fault' in my terminal. I went deeper into that and it is coming from a part of code that I didn't post b/c I thought it doesn't matter. Gonna update the question.

Comment: I think a more pressing coding/design issue is the use of the names `SPIter` and `SAIter`. They appear to be variables defined in some enclosing class or namespace scope. That's ungood because it leaks information from pretty arbitrary implementation details, and may invalidate assumptions in other code about the values of these variables. Instead use local variables.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf thanks for that feedback - I am a total newbie to this part of coding. I am to implement a simple class and its methods, and SPerson and SAccount are its private struct. Since I am working with them in every method, I decided to declare the iterators right in the class and name them respectively to their vectors. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: @LeaPetrášová: declaring them locally is much less problematic. if modern compiler then you can just put `auto` in front of the initializing *assignments*, in order to turn them into declarations with *initializers*. if compiler doesn't support `auto`, then the class can provide `typedef` short names of the relevant iterator types, so that local declarations become less verbose. by the way, the idea of putting such variables in enclosing scope is called **scratchpad variables**. they're mostly universally regarded as evil... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if `SPiter` is valid before you can dereference it, since lower_bound could actually return `SPeople.end()` if the lookup value is not less than any of the elements. Possibly using something like:

```
if ( SPiter != SPeople.end ( ) &&
     (( SPiter -> s_name == name &&
     SPiter -> s_addr == addr ) ||
     SAiter -> s_account == acc )) return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You use default comp for **std::lower_bound** which is sign "<". So it must be rightly overloaded in your case. **std::distance** gives you an index for lower bound but it seems you need lower_bound + 1.

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
size_t iterDistance = distance ( SPeople.begin ( ), SPiter );
```

gives you the index.

However take into account that the next if statement

```
if ( ( SPiter -> s_name == name &&
   SPiter -> s_addr == addr ) ||
   SAiter -> s_account == acc ) return false;
```

is wrong because if the element was not found then you try to access the vectors beyond their sizes. You need to add one more condition

```
if ( ( SPiter != SPeople.end ( ) && SPiter -> s_name == name &&
   SPiter -> s_addr == addr ) ||
   SAiter -> s_account == acc ) return false;
```

Also if a person can have several accounts then it is not enough to check the condition above. You should iterate all elements with the same s_name and s_addr to check whether the account already exists.

I think that instead of the if statement you should do the following

```
while ( SPiter != SPeople.end ( ) &&
        SPiter -> s_name == name &&
        SPiter -> s_addr == addr &&
        SAiter -> s_account != acc )
{
    ++SPiter; ++SAiter;
}

if ( SPiter != SPeople.end ( ) && SPiter -> s_name == name && SPiter -> s_addr == addr )
{
   return false;
}


SPeople.insert( SPiter, personToAdd );
SAccounts.insert( SAiter, accountToAdd );

return true;
```